# Error precompiling assets with Rails - ruby_executable_hooks:14:in `read': No such file or directory - assets:precompile:all (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 3.2.14, ruby 1.9.3p448, and rvm 1.22.11, and I'm on Chapter 2 of railstutorial.org.  I am also running Ubuntu 12.04

I am having a problem precompiling my assets.  When I run the command: `rails assets:precompile` I get the following error:

```
user@user-HP-ProBook-4230s:~/Dropbox/yucg/first_app$ clear; rake assets:precompile --trace

** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in `read': No such file or directory - assets:precompile:all (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/...]
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:55:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:82:in `ruby'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I have no idea what the issue is, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be a problem with ruby 1.9.3-p448. Check out [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967789/rake-assetsprecompile-error-message-no-such-file-or-directory-ruby) for more info. It seems that following these steps:

```
$ rvm gemset empty
$ bundle install
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Would be the fastest resolution.